# C# CefSharp WebView memory issue

Tags: c#, winforms, webview, chromium, cefsharp

I'm running a `Winform` application with `CefSharp` `ChromiumWebBrowser`.

I noticed that after a lot of time that the application run it's take 2527 MB(I take this info from `Task Manager`)
[image]

I done couple of thing to try to decrease it:

```
browser.BrowserSettings.ImageLoading = CefState.Disabled;
```

To remove the photos.

```
CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
```

To close the `Subprocess`.

Both of this things didn't help to decrease the memory. I also tried to check the `ChromiumWebBrowser` page source but when i save it it's only take 2.7 MB.

Any ideas what can be the issue?
How i can try to decrease it more?

## **EDIT**

This is the url:

```
https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=s1142373756_10629735016947342097
```

And i run a `Javascript` method in loop:

```
private void ScrollTop()
{

if (!addScrollTop)
{
String js =  "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
             "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
             "script.text = \"function myFunctionScroll() { " +

                    "try {" +
                        "var element = document;" +
                        "var pageWrap = element.body.children[0];" +

                        "var history = pageWrap.getElementsByClassName('im_history_scrollable_wrap nano-content')[0];" +
                        "history.scrollTop = 0;" +
                    "} catch(err) { return err.message; }" +

                    "return 'done';" +

                 "}\";" +
                 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
    getFromBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(js);
    addScrollTop = true;
}

getFromBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("myFunctionScroll();").ContinueWith(x =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    ScrollTop();
});
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? How does Chrome of the exact same version behave?

Comment: @amaitland `CefSharp 69.0.0`. Didn't understand the second question. How i can check it?

Comment: If you load your website in Chrome 69 does it demonstrate similar memory consumption?  Most memory leaks require upgrading to a newer version of Chromium. If your website is 2.7mb of just html then that is rather large. Most memory leaks are the result of poorly written JavaScript.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks! The page that I'm trying to load is Telegram Web. BTW i saw this post https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1329 and some one recommended on disable couple of thing like plug-in and more, this is something that can maybe help?

Comment: What exactly is `Telegram Web`? Do you have a `URL` and a list of steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/71/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L70 for some command line args. You can do your own research if you need to know more

Comment: @amaitland I just edit the post with the URL to the page and the JavaScript method that i run

Comment: Rewrite your javascript to execute in a timer so it's pure javascript. Then you can load in `Chrome`, open devtools then execute your code. You would need to use `Chrome 69` for an accurate comparison.